# Is there a way to validate access & refresh tokens issued using the Simple OAuth module?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am using the OAuth2 authorization code grant with the Simple OAuth module. Everything is working, however I would like to be able to validate access and refresh tokens from my frontend NodeJS server. Is there an API endpoint to which I can send a token to, and in the response I get information about that token (aka token introspection)? For example, a response telling me the token is expired.

Thanks for all the help in advance, and let me know if I need to clarify the question in any way!

Comment: The question is how to validate JavaScript Web Tokens on other web apps. Do I have that right?

Comment: @cilefen Not quite. I want to validate access tokens I've received from Drupal/Simple OAuth module. I receive an authorization token after the user logs in. I can then exchange that for an access token and refresh token. I want to validate the access and refresh token.

Comment: OAuth sends validity times with the tokens. But you wish to test them further without making an ordinary API call (like a request for some data with the access token), or request a new access token (with the refresh token), correct? The question is whether or not OAuth requires a validation API, does this module provide one, yes?

Comment: @cilefen That is precisely correct. I'm hoping there is a separate API call only for token validation.

Comment: The routes in that module are https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_oauth/-/blob/5.2.x/simple_oauth.routing.yml and the implementable OAuth 2.0 endpoints are documented in this RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.

Comment: @cilefen So the way I'm seeing it there isn't a current implementation for the token introspection endpoint in the Simple OAuth module. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'd need to implement this with a custom API endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure the answer is "no". There is no such route provided by the module.

At this stage this looks like a feature request for the module.